# Transfer learning (classifier) to label other datasets that have not been labeled

Tags: python, dataset, classification, transfer-learning

I have a duty to label a set of Github issues based on their severity. Here are the steps I have made.

1. I built a classification model obtained from a bug dataset which contains a collection of bugs from bugzilla, eclipse, and mozilla that have been labeled based on their severity using SVM / NB / KNN)
2. I have done text processing on a dataset that contains a set of issues from github (but has not been labeled by severity)

Can transfer learning be done using python from a classification model that has been created to label the unlabelled github dataset?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the architecture of your classification model. If you have a transformers model you can check out the code for transfer learning practices from one dataset to another: https://github.com/lemay-ai/lazyTextPredict.